# org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.NoDescriptorForDeclarationException: Descriptor wasn't found for declaration SCRIPT

Tags: android, kotlin, build, dagger

I can’t build a project after trying to add a dagger

I'm new to using kotlin
I use a sample Dagger 2 project at some point my project stopped starting

**Solution Tried:**

Invalidate Caches/Restart
Build -> Clean Project
Update kotlin plugin, used lastest version of kotlin

**build:gradle(Module:app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'

    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
        enabledForTests = true
    }
}



dependencies {
    def multidex_version = "2.0.1" // Check this from the link
    def lifecycle_version = "2.1.0"
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:$multidex_version"

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:${kotlin_version}"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.1.0'
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:1.0.0-rc03'
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.2'
    kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.7.0'

    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.25.2'
    api 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.25.2'

    api 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.25.2'
    api 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.25.2'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.25.2'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.25.2'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-script-runtime:1.3.61'

}
```

**build:gradle(Project)**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.61'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Error log**

gradlew clean assembleDebug

```
Task :app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin FAILED
e: org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.NoDescriptorForDeclarationException: Descriptor wasn't found for declaration SCRIPT
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.BasicAbsentDescriptorHandler.diagnoseDescriptorNotFound(AbsentDescriptorHandler.kt:18
)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.BasicAbsentDescriptorHandler.diagnoseDescriptorNotFound(AbsentDescriptorHandler.kt:17
)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.LazyDeclarationResolver.findClassDescriptor(LazyDeclarationResolver.kt:88)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.LazyDeclarationResolver.getScriptDescriptor(LazyDeclarationResolver.kt:65)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.LazyDeclarationResolver$resolveToDescriptor$1.visitScript(LazyDeclarationResolver.kt:
204)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.LazyDeclarationResolver$resolveToDescriptor$1.visitScript(LazyDeclarationResolver.kt:
94)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtScript.accept(KtScript.java:69)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.LazyDeclarationResolver.resolveToDescriptor(LazyDeclarationResolver.kt:94)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.LazyDeclarationResolver.resolveToDescriptor(LazyDeclarationResolver.kt:91)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.ResolveSession.resolveToDescriptor(ResolveSession.java:329)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.extensions.PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension$doAnalysis$1.invoke(PartialAnalysisHandlerE
xtension.kt:64)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.extensions.PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension$doAnalysis$1.invoke(PartialAnalysisHandlerE
xtension.kt:34)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.extensions.PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.doForEachDeclaration(PartialAnalysisHandler
Extension.kt:121)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.extensions.PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.doForEachDeclaration(PartialAnalysisHandler
Extension.kt:135)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.extensions.PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.doAnalysis(PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.
kt:63)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.doAnalysis(Kapt3Extension.kt:145)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacade
ForJVM.kt:105)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyz
erFacadeForJVM.kt:82)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:557)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:82)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:107)

        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:548)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:177
)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:165)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:55)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:84)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:42)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:104)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:349)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:105)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:237)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.access$compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:37)

        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner$compile$2.invoke(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:79)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:91)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:606)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:99)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1645)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Did you have a Kotlin worksheet (`*.ws.kts`) or something like that somewhere in your source directories, e.g. `src/main/java`? I think `kapt` produces that error because it cannot process files like that.

I resolved it by moving my Kotlin worksheet out of the `src/main/java` and placed it somewhere else.